# How to get user's dbsession id and how to work with expire value in yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I use dbsession and I see the data into mysql table, so dbsession config is working good.

I need to understand if user is online. 
How I can take this user session id?

When I will know user's session id I will take expire number from database. But there is integer value, what this value means? How I can compare it with own time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this way you will only be able to get a list of users who visited your site pages for the last few minutes.

1. Yes, you may store sessions in your database - just put db session settings in your config file and create proper database table. It's described here: 
   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html
   But you will have to change session table and use your own CustomDbSession class.
2. Add 'user_id' integer field to session table schema.
3. Create your custom class which will extend DbSession and rewrite its 'writeSession' method - add saving user_id there if user is not a guest.
4. Next you would want to know/set user authTimeout - it is in config->components->user section.

Now we can get the list of users who visited our site, for example, during last 5 minutes:

```
$expire = Yii::$app->user->authTimeout - 5*60;
(new Query())->select(['user_id'])
            ->from('session')
            ->where('[[expire]]>:expire', [':expire' => $expire])
            ->column();
```

Answer (score 4):

A small addition to Pavel Bariev's correct answer: You don't have to extend the DbSession class to save additional fields to your session table. Simply set the "writeCallback" property via the config. For example:

```
'session'=>[
    'class'=>'yii\web\DbSession',
    'writeCallback'=>function($session)
    {
        return [
            'user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->id,
        ];
    }
],
```

Comment: But this is updating expire time on every page load which is not standard thing. Any workaround for this?